# Setting relative URIs in Firefox web extension parsed DOM

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on a Firefox web extension that saves a new version of the page using the [chrome.downloads.download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download) API within a [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background) script of the extension. The page I want to save is passed to the background script as a string. Before I save it to the hard drive I want to substitute the original `<img>` `src=''` attributes for relative paths.

I can parse the string of the page using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), but whenever I try and set the `src` attributes to a relative path using `.setAttribute()`, Firefox adds the extension key to the URI.

For example:

```
let myParser = new DOMParser();
let myDOM = myParser.parseFromString(originalTextStringOfDOM, "text/html");
const images = myDOM.querySelectorAll('img');
images.forEach(async function(img) {
    img.setAttribute('src','test.png');
}
```

The `src` property ends up set to something like "moz-extension://aa6127fb-0848-47dc-b883-blahblahblah/test.png". Is there any way to set it to simply "test.png"? I can do string substitution on originalTextStringOfDOM but that seems needlessly brittle when I have the element right there already.

Comment: You need to add `<base href="http://foo/bar">` into `<head>`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this will work. Adding the `<base href=''>` element still doesn't allow me to set the `<img src=''>` URI to something relative, it just creates a new absolute path by combining the `src` string with the base `href`. Since I'm writing the html out as a local file, I need a real relative link.

Comment: As you can see in the documentation for `<base>` element it needs a full URL there, which will be used to resolve the relative URLs in the page. This is how DOM works.

Comment: I guess that's the core of my problem: I'm really just looking for an easy way to parse and edit HTML code that doesn't assume it's a real, full webpage. XML doesn't work because the original HTML isn't valid XML. Are there any other native ways to do this?

Comment: I feel we're going in circles. The method I suggested is a solution for exactly this kind of task, if I understand correctly what you want.

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out. I was trying to view the `src` attribute using `console.log(JSON.stringify(img.src))` and Firefox adds on the base path at that point, not on the DOM itself. (myDOM.outerHTML does what I want -- in fact it doesn't look like I even need to set the `<base href=''>` element.) Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Well, yeah, when you access img.src it'll automatically expand to full URL per DOM specification. It's not the same as img.getAttribute('src'). P.S. `<base href=''>` is an invalid thing, there's no way to make img.src return a relative URL.